# How to solve Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: jquery

```
  <!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery.getJSON demo</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="test"></div>

  <script>
  (function() {
    var flickerAPI = "https://api.cryptowat.ch/markets/bitstamp/btcusd/price";
    $.getJSON( flickerAPI )
      .done(function( data ) {
        alert("price: " + data['result'].price + " cost: " + data['allowance'].cost + " remaining: " + data['allowance'].remaining);
      })
      .fail(function() {
        alert("FAIL!");
      });
  })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In IE show returned data in other browser this code return "FAIL!".
In firefox, I use firebug and checked returned data: "CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missed".
How to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin and correct code to work in Firefox?

Comment: If you do not have control over `api.cryptowat.ch`, you can't... - Now, your HTML structure is messed. `<!doctype html>` comes first, then `<html lang="en">` which is a parent of `<head>` and `<body>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

Comment: thank you for answer, I'm messed code while copying them.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably review some CORS tutorials/introductions. A great one is:
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Having said that, the short answer is that the provider of the API needs to allow Cross domain access. Something like the following in an apache config:
`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *`

Unfortunatly, not something you can do much about.  In some situations switching to 'JSONP' as the dataType works. In your case, you could change your call to `$.getJSON` to something like

```
$.ajax({
   url: flickerAPI,
   dataType: 'JSON',
   jsonpCallback: 'callback',
   type: 'GET',
})
```

However, this requires that the server knows how to respond to JSONP, and it looks like cryptowat.ch does not.

Comment: thanks, I will check link. I have try similar code but without success.